# How to draw dash-dotted curves using MetaPost?

Tags: plot, metapost

Is it possible to (easily) draw dash-dotted curves in MetaPost, i.e. curves that alternate between a dash and a dot?

For either dashed or dotted curves, I use the `draw` command and end it with `dashed evenly` or `dashed withdots`, respectively.

Does MetaPost include a similar option for dash-dotted curves?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The definition of `withdots` is

```
dashpattern(off 2.5 on 0 off 2.5)
```

while `evenly` is

```
dashpattern(on 3 off 3)
```

Thus something like

```
beginfig(32);
draw dashpattern(on 3 off 3 on 0 off 3) dashed evenly;
picture p;
p=currentpicture;
currentpicture:=nullpicture;
draw fullcircle scaled 1cm xscaled 3 dashed p;
endfig;
end.
```

taken from figure 32 in the Metapost manual will alternate dashes and dots.

[image]

Comment: @Gassa Yes, thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 2):

not that it matters, but for the record the definitions of withdots (widthdots is a typo) and evenly are reversed in the above. actual definitions from plain.mp:

```
evenly=dashpattern(on 3 off 3); % `dashed evenly'
withdots=dashpattern(off 2.5 on 0 off 2.5); % `dashed withdots'
```